# How can I make a button to stop the timer in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

```
import time
print("The timer on this project Will start")

#Ask To Begin
start = input('Would you like to begin learning now? (yes / no):')
if start == 'yes':
    timeloop = True

#variable to keep the time
Sec = 0
Min = 0

#Begin process
timeloop = start
while timeloop:
   Sec +=1
   print(str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
   time.sleep(1)
   if Sec == 60:
       Sec = 0
       Min +=1
       print(str(Min) + " Minute ")
```

This is my timer program so far but I am not sure How I can get it to stop once it starts in the command prompt?. I want to be able to press X and have the code pause. Or perhaps press Y and then it resumes, and Z just closes the program all together, but I have no idea as to how.

Comment: Pick one from [`[python] read keyboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+read+keyboard)

Comment: If you're running this from Window's command prompt, you should be able to press the keys Ctrl + Break at the same time to stop the script's execution. If you don't have a Break key, try Ctrl + C. If you want a graphical Button to press, you'll need to create a GUI for your program, which would take a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep actually stop the execution of the current process the code is running on. If you want to keep time and still make the process responsive, you may want to use a thread to keep time and  install the keyboard package to use keyboard.is_pressed()!

This article is really good:
https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#what-is-a-thread